# Resharper extract interface - default options

Tags: resharper, rider, resharper-6.1

The defaults in the Extract Interface dialogue box for Resharper are "Place beside" and none of the members checked.  Is there anyway to change this default?  I'd rather "Place in another file" and all public members was checked (i.e. the opposite).

Comment: 10 years later, I'd like to know how to do exactly this in JetBrains Rider!